# How to use page slider horizontally in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to move my page to left using page slider in html, I have above 6 products so now I'm showing 4 products at a time in my page but I have more than 6 products when I was in the product page the slider must start moving left side and when we are clicking with mouse then also the page slider should work properly.

```
<html>
    <div class="col-1-4">
        <div class="wrap-col">
            <div class="box maxheight1">
                <img src="images/box1_img1.png" alt="">
                    <div class="text1">
                        <a href="#">Food Central</a>
                    </div>Food central is a mobile application ......................
                    <div class="button" style="color:#334960">
                        <a href="#">Read More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: how you expecting this to move left ? have you added any css or js ? if yes then add here.

Comment: Give fiddler code plz

Comment: i'm new to html and java script so i want that slider code for my site

Answer (score 0):

it is with `overflow-x:scroll;`

It would be that :

```
div .wrap-col { 
    width:800px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
div .wrap-col div {
    width:4000px;
}
```